# Elasticsearch query to find substrings of a query string

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am working on a problem of identifying email patterns if you are given an email address.
I have a dataset of surnames. If I pass an email address to elasticsearch it should return matching surnames inside that email address. In other words I am looking for a method to find out all the results where results are substring of query string.
For example, if my query string is *ajohnson* then elasticsearch should return me *johnson* from surname dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your [Custom Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) with [NGram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) and use it as [`search_analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-analyzer.html). As a result your query string can be split into n-grams and each n-gram will be searched in a surname.